# Displaying XML dynamically using PHP and URL variables

Tags: php, xml, url, dynamic

I'm a game writer and designer and we use XML files for our dialogue engine. I'm trying to display the dialogue on a website for my team to see, and I'd like to be able to dynamically display certain parts or 'chapters' of the XML based on a URL variable. I'm using PHP for this.

Here is a very simple example of how our XML is structured:

```
<dialogues>
    <dialogue id="0">
        <line id="0_1" name="John">Line 1</line>
        <line id="0_2" name="Eric">Line 2</line>
        <line id="0_3" name="Ben">Line 3</line>
    </dialogue>
    <dialogue id="1">
        <line id="1_1" name="Sarah">Line 1</line>
        <line id="1_2" name="Jessica">Line 2</line>
        <line id="1_3" name="Kelly">Line 3</line>
    </dialogue>
</dialogues>
```

What I'd like to do is display the lines of specific `dialogue` blocks based on a variable I pass through the URL. Here is my PHP so far.

```
$url = "dialogues.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$chapter = $_GET['c'];

    foreach($xml->dialogue->line as $dialogue)
    {
        echo '<p class="id">id: ' . $dialogue["id"] . '</p>';
        echo '<p class="name">' . $dialogue["name"] . '</p>';
        echo $dialogue."<br/>";
    }
```

So you can see that I've got a `$chapter` variable that I would get with `?c=` in the URL, I just don't know what to do from there. What I would do to this code to only display, say, the lines within `<dialogue id="1">` based on `?c=1` in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using xpath; it's designed for this sort of situation.  Here's an example of how to get each line of dialogue.

```
foreach ($xml->xpath("//dialogue[@*])/line") as $line)
     echo $line;
```

Here's a helpful reference sourcce https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath

Comment: has happened to me in the past. :) XML?  first thought: xpath :)  It also works on well formed html.  If this solved your problem, please mark it so. :)